# Custom header in fetch not hitting server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When i create header object and pass it , it is not working, it is not even hitting the server

```
const post = async (url, request) => {
let testHeader = new Headers();
testHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
testHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const response = await fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: testHeader,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    }
);
return responseHandler(request, response);
};
```

but when i pass the headers like this , it works with out any issues

```
const post = async (url, request) => {
const response = await fetch(url,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    }
  );
  return responseHandler(request, response);
  };
```